# Lookup Field in MySQL

Tags: database

I have a set of categories for a MySQL database that wont change much, but might on occasion. (maybe around a dozen choices)

For this sort of situation, where answers are basically multiple choice, should I just use a text field in my main table then in PHP limit the answers, or make a separate table to hold the lookup values then store the id from the category table in the main table?

Just looking for normalization best practices :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, php5, or really even mysql, the only tag i see as pertinent is database

Comment: It has to do with PHP/5 in that the alternative is managing the answers in PHP, in this case - and it's MySQL, not Access or for example Microsoft SQL Server. I figured more detail was better than less.

Comment: but this is not php or mysql specific, i can't think of another web framework / database that this doesn't apply to

Comment: I disagree with you, but this is a circular argument. I removed all the tags except database - the internet is safe now dtarh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are OK, they have the following consequences:

- Text field means the set of answers is maintained in the PHP code
- Lookup table means the set of answers is maintained in the database

I think it depends if they are "data" (-> database) or really part of the application (-> definitely PHP code, e.g. if you have `if ($cat == 'x') { ... }` anywhere in your code.)

It sounds to me more like they are data so in that case put them in a table.

Comment: just because you are comparing a variable to a static doesn't mean that static belongs only in code..

Answer (score 4):

Normalization best practice is that you always assume stuff can and will change. So make another table. :)

Comment: As it turns out you're right already, heh. I realized I could load and cache categories for other purposes as well, and manage them strictly from the database.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomend that you maintain a table of categories holding an ID and and category name and any other columns you feel fit to add to this table. Then in any other tables reference to this categories table by its ID.

You SQL will need to do LEFT JOIN or select from both tables where sometable.cid = categories.id

Answer (score 0):

you should always use a separate table, I can't see a reason not to, especially if you ever need to do any sort of reporting etc.